# inconsistent index with different periods get just one type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I download a df from the internet which is basically like this. I just want to keep the rows which are daily values. Is there any possibility of doing this, so every time I download the df I get until the last daily value?

| Date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 21-02-2013 | 1231 |
| 22-02-2013 | 323 |
| 23-02-2013 | 343 |
| ... | ... |
| 12-10-2020 | 432 |
| Monthly |  |
| 02-2013 | 2655 |
| 03-2013 | 321 |
| ... | ... |
| Yearly |  |
| Total 2013 | 3213 |
| Total 2020 | 543 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could perform a [regex match](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) on the 'Date' column; for given example data

```
df
Out[10]: 
          Date   name
0   21-02-2013   1231
1   22-02-2013    323
2   23-02-2013    343
3          ...    ...
4   12-10-2020    432
5      Monthly    NaN
6      02-2013   2655
7      03-2013    321
8          ...    ...
9       Yearly    NaN
10  Total 2013   3213
11  Total 2020    543
```

that would be

```
df.loc[df['Date'].str.match('[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}')]
Out[11]: 
         Date   name
0  21-02-2013   1231
1  22-02-2013    323
2  23-02-2013    343
4  12-10-2020    432

# or if you need it to be even more specific:
# df.loc[df['Date'].str.fullmatch('[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}')]
```

Comment: You might want [fullmatch](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) here depending on desired behaviour.

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks for the hint! Added it as a comment. I think it depends how "clean" the OP's input is (trailing whitespaces etc.) what is most useful here.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks!

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks!